# Matlab fftshift not working correctly

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-analysis

I am trying to plot the frequency spectrum of a sinewave with frequency 77.5 kHz and amplitude 2. Only the zero-point is not correct, it is shifted to the left. 
My code:

```
f1=77.5e3; % frequency of the sinewave 
a1=2; % amplitude of the sinewave 

Fs = 1.55e6; % sampling frequency
dt=1/Fs; % step size 
maxtime = 5*(1/f1);
t=0:dt:maxtime; % time interval in which we want to plot 

x=a1*sin(2*pi*f1*t); % the values for the sinewave

N=length(t);  % this is how many samples we have in the time-domain
X=fft(x)/N; 
X=fftshift(X);
f=[-N/2:1:N/2-1]*Fs/N;  % creates a frequency axis 

figure(1)
plot(f,abs(X))
title('Magnitude Spectrum of x(t)')
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ylabel('|X(f)|')
```

When I run this code I get an incorrect frequency spectrum. Can anyone help me out?

Edit: the figure I get when running this code:
[image: Incorrect spectrum I get]

Besides the incorrect zero-point I also get an incorrect frequency when I count it out myself from the plot. I'm just not sure how I should plot such a sinewave with frequency 77.5kHz, amplitude 2 and sampling frequency 1.55 MHz

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: why do you use `fftshift`?? why not just `fft(x,N)/N`?

Comment: I am new to Matlab and this was in the explanation I found. Isn't `fftshift` necessary?

Comment: No it is not, just use `fft(x,N)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct as it is. But your signal, once made periodic, is not just a sine wave (there is a discontinuity, because the 1st and last samples of x are the same).

You can try removing 1 sample at the end:

```
t=0:dt:maxtime; % time interval in which we want to plot 
t = t(1:end-1);
```

Now the peak is at f1.